# How to use the tkinter Entry widget?

Tags: python, class, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm trying to insert an `Entry` field in my `tkinter`-based GUI.
It has three different "pages" as classes with buttons etc, but the `Entry` field doesn't work.

I want to put the entry field in the last page (`class PageTwo`). Then I just want to click one of the check buttons and I would be OK if the entered text would show as print, or in another text field in the GUI.
Update: I changed the entry code to `controller.wordde = Entry(self)`
and made a button `print(controller.wordde.get())`

The error code I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\x\g_4.py", line 147, in <module>
    app = SeaofBTCapp()
  File "C:\x\g_4.py", line 40, in __init__
    frame = F(container, self)
  File "C:\x\g_4.py", line 141, in __init__
    wordde.grid(row=3, column=1)
NameError: name 'wordde' is not defined
```

This is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import csv
import random
import sys

z = random.randint(1,50)
with open('vokabelnsemicolon.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    delist = []
    enlist = []
    for row in readCSV:
        eng = row[1]
        deu = row[0]

        delist.append(deu)
        enlist.append(eng)

LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)


class SeaofBTCapp(tk.Tk):


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):


        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):


    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Start Page", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button = tk.Button(self, text="German -> English",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="-> English -> German",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button2.pack()



#German -> English
class PageOne(tk.Frame):


    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="German -> English", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.grid(row=0, column=0)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.grid(row=1, column=1)

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="English -> German",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button2.grid(row=2, column=1)

        button3 = tk.Button(self, text="Check",
                            command=None)
        button3.grid(row=4, column=1)

        #text field for entry box
        Label(self, text='"'+enlist[z]+'"'+ ' in english is: ').grid(row=3, column=0)

        #entry field
        worden = Entry(self)
        worden.grid(row=3, column=1)


#English -> German
class PageTwo(tk.Frame):


    def checkybutton(self):
        print('checkbutton!')  

    def checkybutton2(self):
        print(controller.wordde.get())

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="English -> German", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.grid(row=0, column=0)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.grid(row=1, column=1)

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="German -> English",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button2.grid(row=2, column=1)
        #text field for entry box
        Label(self, text='"'+delist[z]+'"'+ ' in german is: ').grid(row=3, column=0)


        button3 = tk.Button(self, text="checkbutton",
                            command=self.checkybutton)
        button3.grid(row=4, column=1)


        button4 = tk.Button(self, text="checkbutton 2",
                            command=self.checkybutton2)
        button4.grid(row=4, column=0)


        #entry field
        controller.wordde = Entry(self)

        wordde.grid(row=3, column=1)

        txt = Text(self, width=35, height=1, wrap=WORD)
        txt.grid(row=5, columnspan=2, sticky=W)    


app = SeaofBTCapp()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: So I can write in the field, but I cant get the entered letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to store the entry somewhere, to be able to refer to it later.

For your code, it seems the best place to store it is in the controller, as it is accessible on all pages:

instead of `worden = Entry(self)` use:

```
controller.worden = Entry(self)
```

That will store a reference to your entry instance in the controller object. Later you can use `controller.worden.get()` to retrieve the value:

```
print(controller.worden.get())
```

---

EDIT: To clarify - `controller` is an instance of the `SeaofBTCapp` class created here:

```
app = SeaofBTCapp()
```

That instance is passed to the other classes' `__init__` here:

```
for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):
    frame = F(container, self)  # self is the controller
```

Now, since you will need access to the `controller` in other methods that are not `__init__`, you have to also store a reference to the controller in the instances of those classes.

Change `__init__` in the `StartPage`, `PageOne` and `PageTwo` classes to do this:

```
def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.controller = controller
    #.... rest of the method here ...
```

That means each page istance has a reference to the `controller` stored as an attribute. Now, in the methods of those classes that are not `__init__`, you can access that object by using `self.controller`:

```
def checkybutton2(self):
    print(self.controller.wordde.get())
```

Comment: Hi nosklo. Thank you for your reply. I forgot to say that the console gives me the error message "NameError: name 'wordde' is not defined". I tried your suggestion but it still says the same... Any more ideas?

Comment: @Patoche my example was for the variable `worden` - you can do the same for the variable `wordde`

Comment: It should work - maybe edit the question and add the new code and the error you're getting, then?

Comment: ok, now, since you're storing the entry in the `controller`, you must use it to refer to the entry every time  @Patoche , so, `wordde.grid(row=3, column=1)` becomes `controller.wordde.grid(row=3, column=1)` and the same for every reference to `wordde`

Comment: I replaced all of it. Now I have  def checkybutton2(self):print(controller.wordde.get()), controller.wordde = Entry(self)  and  controller.wordde.grid(row=3, column=1)  When entering text and clicking on the "checkbutton2" i get the error: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\x\g_4.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\x\g_4.py", line 111, in checkybutton2
    print(controller.wordde.get())
NameError: name 'controller' is not defined

Comment: @Patoche I edited my answer and added some explanation to fix this.

Comment: It works! Thank you for your help and you excellent explanation nosklo!